# setRepeating() of AlarmManager does not repeat after update apk Versioncode

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, alarm, android-alarms

`setRepeating()` of AlarmManager does not repeat after update apk Versioncode

Is there any way to run it automatically, right after update apk?
The time is already set on previous versioncode, but the alarms work only when the phone restarted.

```
//SET ALARM
Cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
Cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
Cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
Cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Editor e = sharedPrefs.edit();
e.putLong("userTime", Cal.getTimeInMillis());
e.commit();
mytime.setSummary(DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getBaseContext())
        .format(new Date(Cal.getTimeInMillis())));

new AlarmTask(UserSettingActivity.this, Cal).run();
```

class  AlarmTask implements Runnable:

```
private final Calendar date;
private final AlarmManager am;
private final Context context;

public AlarmTask(Context context, Calendar date) {
    this.context = context;
    this.am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    this.date = date;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotifyService.class);
    intent.putExtra(NotifyService.INTENT_NOTIFY, true);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: you can use a broadcast with custom logic to trigger alarm !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Solved, service must be restarted after version update. add manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".Launcher" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Launcher Class

```
public class Launcher extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        context.stopService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), NotifyService.class));
        context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), NotifyService.class));

    }
}
```